# Is the tour operator with the website en.arcticexpedition.ru still operating?

Tags: russia, tours

I found the tour operator http://en.arcticexpedition.ru on the web and I'm interested in its tour in remote parts of Russia. However, the latest departure date of the tour in this website is 2015. I also sent an email to them, but it failed as their email address seems not able to receive the email.

I also cannot find other tours that offer similar tours to parts of Russia such as Bartak, Dzhugdzhur and Dusse Alin.

So, is that tour operator still in operation? If not, is there any other tour operator that provides tours to areas that en.arcticexpedition.ru provided? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like they aren't working for now. I don't think that you can find one in English

Comment: @VMAtm Yesterday I contacted them through skype (provided in the russian site)and somebody replied me.I ask for their email but the email address they gave is totally different from the website and looks like personal email more than a company email... I still waiting for their reply...

Comment: Their email is personal even on site

Comment: They actually have 3 email in their site(one in english main page ,one in russian main page and one in "contact us")

Comment: @VMAtm Sorry, they have 4 emails.....